# Code to generate a dictionary from two lists

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, hash-map

I created a script to perform a union on 2 lists: keys and words. I needed to create a dictionary from them. If there are more keys than words, missing words are replaced with "None". Any excess words are removed.

How can I improve this code to be more compact and perform better?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import random
import string
from itertools import zip_longest
def generator(listKeys,listWords):

    diff = len(listKeys)-len(listWords)
    if diff > 0:
        for i in range(0,diff):
            listWords.append(None)
    elif diff<0:
        listWords = listWords[0:len(listKeys)]

    done = dict(zip(listKeys,listWords))
    return done

if __name__ == "__main__":
    listKeys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
    listWords = [94, 87, 92, 5, 75, 91, 60, 5]
    print("Keys more values:\nKeys: %s \nValues %s\nResult: %s\n" % (listKeys, listWords,generator(listKeys,listWords)))

    listKeys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
    listWords = [9, 65, 18, 80, 2, 16, 81, 98, 73, 2, 88, 30, 1, 78, 92]
    print("Values more keys:\nKeys: %s \nValues %s\nResult: %s\n" % (listKeys, listWords,generator(listKeys,listWords)))

    listKeys = []
    listWords = []

    for i in range(0,random.randrange(5,15)):
        listKeys.append(list(string.ascii_lowercase)[i])

    for i in range(0,random.randrange(6,16)):
        listWords.append(random.randrange(0,100))

    print("Random:\nKeys: %s \nValues %s\nResult: %s\n" % (listKeys, listWords,generator(listKeys,listWords)))
```

Comment: thanks for editing. English is no my native language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` and `itertools.zip_longest` do exactly what you are looking for, you only need to choose between the two depending on the lengths of the lists:

```
def generator(listKeys, listWords):
    if len(listKeys) > len(listWords):
        zipped = zip_longest(listKeys, listWords)
    else:
        zipped = zip(listKeys, listWords)
    return dict(zipped)
```

This can even be shortened to

```
def generator(listKeys, listWords):
    my_zip = zip_longest if len(listKeys) > len(listWords) else zip
    return dict(my_zip(listKeys, listWords))
```

Note that `generator` is not a good name for this function as [the word generator has a particular meaning in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

Answer (score 1):

**Style and tools**

Your code looks weird : you have line breaks in unexpected places but not in a few expected places (such as before defining a function), whitespaces are not consistent. In Python, you'll find [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), a style guide that can be quite helpful to you. Even better, you'll also find tools to detect problems such as [pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) and to fix them such as [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8).

You'll also find various other tools to check your code such as `pylint` or `pychecker` and `pyflakes`. They can be useful to find problems in your code. For instance, `lists2.py:4: 'zip_longest' imported but unused` and `Unused variable 'i' (unused-variable)` (for your information, `_` is the usual name for throw-way variables in Python).

Finally, your variable names do not follow the convention.

Once this is done, your code looks like :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""Docstring for the module."""
import random
import string


def generator(keys, words):
    """Docstring for the function."""
    diff = len(keys) - len(words)
    if diff > 0:
        for _ in range(0, diff):
            words.append(None)
    elif diff < 0:
        words = words[0:len(keys)]

    done = dict(zip(keys, words))
    return done

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
            'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
    words = [94, 87, 92, 5, 75, 91, 60, 5]
    print("Keys more values:\nKeys: %s \nValues %s\nResult: %s\n" %
          (keys, words, generator(keys, words)))

    keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
    words = [9, 65, 18, 80, 2, 16, 81, 98, 73, 2, 88, 30, 1, 78, 92]
    print("Values more keys:\nKeys: %s \nValues %s\nResult: %s\n" %
          (keys, words, generator(keys, words)))

    keys = []
    words = []

    for i in range(0, random.randrange(5, 15)):
        keys.append(list(string.ascii_lowercase)[i])

    for i in range(0, random.randrange(6, 16)):
        words.append(random.randrange(0, 100))

    print("Random:\nKeys: %s \nValues %s\nResult: %s\n" %
          (keys, words, generator(keys, words)))
```

**Making things more simple**

First, `range(0, foo)` can be replaced by `range(foo)`.

Then, you can replace `x = []; for i in bar: x.append(foo())` with list comprehension : `x = [foo() for i in bar]`.

Your code becomes :

```
keys = [list(string.ascii_lowercase)[i] for i in range(random.randrange(5, 15))]
words = [random.randrange(0, 100) for i in range(random.randrange(6, 16))]
```

Even better, you probably don't need to get letters individually from `string.ascii_lowercase`. You can just use `list(string.ascii_lowercase[:X])`.

Also, we don"t really need `keys` to be a list. At the end of the day, we just want it to be iterable and strings are iterable.

```
keys = string.ascii_lowercase[:random.randrange(5, 15)]
words = [random.randrange(0, 100) for _ in range(random.randrange(6, 16))]
```

Finally, you don't need to store your value in a variable to return it.

Your code now looks like :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""Docstring for the module."""
import random
import string


def generator(keys, words):
    """Docstring for the function."""
    diff = len(keys) - len(words)
    if diff > 0:
        for _ in range(diff):
            words.append(None)
    elif diff < 0:
        words = words[0:len(keys)]

    return dict(zip(keys, words))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
            'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
    words = [94, 87, 92, 5, 75, 91, 60, 5]
    print("Keys more values:\nKeys: %s \nValues %s\nResult: %s\n" %
          (keys, words, generator(keys, words)))

    keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
    words = [9, 65, 18, 80, 2, 16, 81, 98, 73, 2, 88, 30, 1, 78, 92]
    print("Values more keys:\nKeys: %s \nValues %s\nResult: %s\n" %
          (keys, words, generator(keys, words)))

    keys = string.ascii_lowercase[:random.randrange(5, 15)]
    words = [random.randrange(0, 100) for _ in range(random.randrange(6, 16))]

    print("Random:\nKeys: %s \nValues %s\nResult: %s\n" %
          (keys, words, generator(keys, words)))
```

Other comments have been given about the code you actually care about :-)

**Likely to be a bug**

Once probably wouldn't expect neither `keys`, nor `words` to be affected by your function. However, `words` might get updated. This is definitly something you should try to avoid.

You could write something like :

```
def generator(keys, words):
    """Docstring for the function."""
    diff = len(keys) - len(words)
    if diff > 0:
        words = words + [None] * diff
    elif diff < 0:
        words = words[0:len(keys)]

    return dict(zip(keys, words))
```